# SQL SERVER Install change Hard disk permissions?

Tags: sql-server, installation

I did an install of SQL SErver 2008 and the client wanted to have the data file at the root of the hard disk, and the log file at the root of another hard disk. 
Prior to me doing install I could browse those harddisks because I am a member of the local admins.  After the install I got permission denied.
To get around this, I had to grant myself the ability to take ownership of hard disks, which I went to security and set myself as the owner, and then give myself specific rights to each of the harddisks, even though there was local admins already assigned the rights to do everything.

So is there something I don't know about installing sql server data directories to the root directory that affects the permissions?  There were files there before and after the install.

Comment: "data file at the root of the hard disk" *shudder*

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be done to prevent data and log files from being modified by users.  Details are in the following article from MSDN:

[Securing Data and Log Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189128.aspx)

Comment: thanks, that article give me some insight. However it wasn't just the .mdf/.ldf files that were locked, but the entire G drive that I pointed too. Now even though local admins have complete access in security I have to list out users individually.  I was reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281941.aspx to see if there was some exceptions, but none found.  thanks again - maybe i did something quirky in the install.